# Java: Return unknown generic type in method

Tags: java, generics

The method

```
Filter<T,U> connect(final Filter<T,U> filter) {
...
return filter
}
```

is in a class

```
class Pipe<T>
```

I get the Error "Cannot resolve U".
The idea is to just generically return the same filter with the same two types without knowing the U type. How do i do that?

The goal is to be able to chain without providing type parameters, when they are not necessary because they do not get modified:

```
(new Pipe<Integer>).connect(new Filter<>(...)).connect(new Pipe<>)...
```

The second Pipe after the Filter in the above expamle shall implicitly be of the generic type Integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make your [method generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). To do this simply add generic type `U` to its signature right before return type:

```
<U> Filter<T,U> connect(final Filter<T,U> filter) {
    ...
    return filter
}
```